# Email appear as null

Tags: android, kotlin

I've the below `XML` form for password reset, where the user enter the email and click submit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.LoginFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

        <EditText                               // This is read as null!
            android:id="@+id/myEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And in the fragment file, I've:

```
class ResetPasswordFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ResetPasswordFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reset_password, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val email = myEmail.text.toString().trim()   // This is null!

        reset.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Email entered is: $email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener({ task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to send reset email!: ${task.exception}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

In the `val email = myEmail.text.toString().trim()` it gives `null`, while `val email = myEmail.text` is showing the correct input as `Editable`, but this not accepted by the `auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)` as the input is required to be `String`

Comment: Where are you defining `myEmail`?

Comment: @cricket_007 with `Kotlin` the `findViewById` is no more required

Comment: @HasanAYousef it's depends upon whether OP is using kotlin extension or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the input, when the button is clicked otherwise `onactivitycreated` executes and there is no input in edittext and gives you `null`.

Take the input from edittext when user press the button and input is available in edittext, as shown below

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


        reset.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Email entered is: $email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            val email = myEmail.text.toString().trim()
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener({ task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to send reset email!: ${task.exception}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin doesn't have 'lazy evaluation' :-) so you should get the email value inside `reset.setOnClickListener`, or the value will be gotten when `onActivityCreated` is executing, and not modified at the rest of execution including clicking the button.